# NodeJS Email Validation

Tags: node.js, api, express, authentication, email-validation

I am currently writing the authentication portion of a **REST API** on NodeJS. To keep thing's short, what I am trying to do is verify the user's email. The application is properly working, the only problem I'm having is that when I send the verification URL on the body of the email, the route I have handling that is a `GET` which is updating some fields on the database. I know this should be handled by a `POST` or `PUT` but those can't be used inside emails (I believe).

What logics have you guys used before for handling such requests?

Thanks!

Comment: You should stick to GET and pass verification hash as get param i.e. yourapi.com/verify?hash=afhauehfiuh it also depends on your implementation, so It would be great if you would provide additional data about framework you are using, or example of your code.